# Is there a way to record a conversation using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, audio, microphone, speaker

I've been playing with a couple of scripts: one [records the system's audio output](https://bartsimons.me/recording-system-audio-through-wasapi-with-powershell/) and the other [records the computer's microphone](https://github.com/PowerShellMafia/PowerSploit/blob/master/Exfiltration/Get-MicrophoneAudio.ps1). However, what I want to do is be able to record both audio output and microphone input simultaneously so that I can save both sides of the conversations (ideally to MP3, but WAV will do). Anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered just... trying? 1) Start both recordings, 2) have a conversation, 3) stop both recordings - then 4) all you need to figure out is how to mix two audio files programmatically :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - That's an interesting idea. I've never used PowerShell to run two scripts/processes simultaneously. Is there a best practice way to do that, ideally from within one master script?